# Unable to add the number to the array. Error Cannot read property

Tags: angular

I have a method that generates an array based on the min and max provided to it. I am getting an error while pushing the value to the method. The error states that Cannot read property genArray. Not sure what the problem is

```
public genArray: number[]; 



  ngOnInit() {

        generateArray(1000,20000);  
     });



   function generateArray(min: any, max: any) 
   {
    let count = min;
    for(count=min; count<=max; count= count + 5000)
       {
         console.log(count);
         this.genArray.push(count);
       };

   };
```

I am listing my complete code below

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { StressTestAnalysis } from '../../../../api/dtos';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-stress-test-analysis',
      templateUrl: './stress-test-analysis.component.html',
    })
    export class StressTestAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {
      isExpanded = false;
      showTable = true;
      @Input() results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];


      chartSeries : Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];


      minYAxis : number;
      maxYAxis : number;

     public genArray: number[] = [];

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {

         this.results.map(r => {
            this.chartSeries.push(r);
            let myArray = this.generateArray(1000,20000); 
         });

       // Function that generates the array based on the min and max derived from the previous method
       private generateArray(min: any, max: any) 
       {
        let count = min;
        for(count=min; count<=max; count= count + 5000)
           {
             console.log(count);
             this.genArray.push(count);
           }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare and intialize the array before using it and properly declare your function `generateArray()` in the component.

```
  public genArray: number[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {

        this.generateArray(1000,20000);  
     });



   private generateArray(min: any, max: any) 
   {
    let count = min;
    for(count=min; count<=max; count= count + 5000)
       {
         console.log(count);
         this.genArray.push(count);
       };

   };
```

Comment: I have tried the above as well as how i have done in my post but both dont work

Comment: See updated code. I missed that you didn't declare your function properly.

Comment: I have updated my post with your code under the section complete code. I am getting red squigly under keyword private saying declaration or statement expected.

Comment: i was missing a closing braket after ngOnit. silly mistake. resolved

Comment: Nice, good find. Those dang closing brackets will get you sometimes... Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `genArray` has to be initialized like this:

```
public genArray: number[] = [];
```

---

Maybe you should do this with a function-like solution, and return with the array, so:

```
public genArray: number[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.genArray = generateArray(1000, 20000);
});
```

And your function:

```
generateArray(min: any, max: any): number[] {
    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (let count = min; count <= max; count = count + 5000) {
        arr.push(count);
    };
    return arr;
}
```